# How to display user specific data?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore database that stores information on clients. Currently it allows users to add, edit, and delete client information. However there is no privacy between users, for example user a can see and alter user b and user c's clients. I use firebase for creating and registering users, and firestore to store the client information. How do I make it so that users can only see and alter clients they created?

Comment: Take some time to learn about security rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: @DougStevenson I have read over the docs but I'm having a difficult time understanding how to approach setting up the rules to limit users to only their data. My database is setup like /clients. I've tried using match /clients/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }  
I believe I need to figure out how to attach the users uid to the clients now

Comment: Did you read the section that specifically talks about per user data?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication

Comment: Yes I've tried to apply the rule and I'm able to create and add clients but unable to view them

Comment: The I suggest you ask a question here that explains what you're trying to do, shows all relevant code, and states exactly what you're doing that's different that what you expect.

Comment: store a createdBy string field and chack if the request.auth.uid === createdBy

Comment: @Firebaser I've made a similar adjustment to my code, I have posted an updated version with it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978137/unable-to-get-client-data-to-display-firestore